# How to write a bsoncxx::document::element to the console

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I have the [following function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039606/query-nested-bson-documents-with-mongo-c-driver) that gets a value out of a `BSON` document when given a sequence of keys:

```
bsoncxx::document::element deepFieldAccess(bsoncxx::document::view bsonObj, const std::vector<std::string>& path) {

    if (path.empty())
        return {};

    auto keysIter = path.begin();
    const auto keysEnd = path.end();

    auto currElement = bsonObj[*(keysIter++)];
    while (currElement && (keysIter != keysEnd))
        currElement = currElement[*(keysIter++)];

    return currElement;
}
```

The returned `bsoncxx::document::element` can hold a value of any type (`int32`, `document`, `array`, `utf8`, etc). How can I write this element to the console via `std::cout`?

Ideally, I would just have to do:

```
bsoncxx::document::element myElement = deepFieldAccess(bsonObjView, currQuery);
std::cout << myElement << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't print `bsoncxx::document::element`, but we can print `bsoncxx::document::view`. So just convert one into the other and clean up the resulting string. It's ugly and inefficient but works for quickly looking up the value of a `bsoncxx::document::element`.

```
std::string turnQueryResultIntoString(bsoncxx::document::element queryResult) {

    // check if no result for this query was found
    if (!queryResult) {
        return "[NO QUERY RESULT]";
    }

    // hax
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document basic_builder{};
    basic_builder.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp("Your Query Result is the following value ", queryResult.get_value()));

    // clean up resulting string
    std::string rawResult = bsoncxx::to_json(basic_builder.view());
    std::string frontPartRemoved = rawResult.substr(rawResult.find(":") + 2);
    std::string backPartRemoved = frontPartRemoved.substr(0, frontPartRemoved.size() - 2);

    return backPartRemoved;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean like this ?

```
bsoncxx::document::element myElement = deepFieldAccess(bsonObjView, currQuery);
std::cout << myElement.get_utf8().value.to_string() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

The `bsoncxx::document::view` type has a defined conversion to JSON, represented as a `std::string` by way of the function `bsoncxx::to_json` in the `bsoncxx/json.hpp` header. The individual `b_xyz` types do not offer such a conversion, because elements not contained within a document or array structure aren't necessarily JSON. You are free though to form your own `to_string` function, and define it for each of the declared BSON types.

Comment: So we can print views (as shown for example [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/fc9a44325e03bb8bb166e814caeb23413b4ba7af/examples/bsoncxx/view_and_value.cpp#L56)). Is it possible to convert the bsoncxx::document::element to a view and then print it? All I want is to inspect what the above function returns, is there some other built in way to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "because elements not contained within a document or array structure aren't necessarily JSON"? As far as I understand, all the elements I want to print are contained in a document (the above function gets the elements out of a `bsoncxx::document::view`).

Comment: @AnnaVopureta - The point is that perhaps only documents and arrays have a valid representation as JSON. It isn't clear, for instance, that a raw string not contained within `{ ... }` or `[ ... ]` is actually JSON. Opinions differ. So how should the `to_json` function handle the `b_utf8` type, for instance?  The driver takes a conservative approach and declares that only `document` like types have a canonical transformation to JSON. If you want to write your own `to_string` function, just provide an overload for each `b_` type and make it do whatever you like.

Comment: So after I overload each `b_` type `to_string` function, I can just do `std::cout << myElement;` where `bsoncxx::document::element myElement = deepFieldAccess(bsonObjView, currQuery);` ? I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Well, for that exact syntax you would need to write overloads for `std::ostream`. Like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const bsoncxx::b_double& value)` and `std::ostream& opoerator<<(std::ostream& stream, const bsoncxx::b_utf8& value)`, etc. Then that would work as written.

Comment: What do you think about the solution I posted, do you see any issues with it? Can you imagine some case where it could fail?